# vb.net lamba expression to select all values between lower and upper values plus the next lower and upper value

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I need some help with a lamda expression to get a subset of range of values. I have a lower and upper value, and getting everything between them seems easy enough, but I also need the next lower and higher value to be included. I can do each of these seperately, but would like to do it in one shot if possible.

The range I need the subset from has 150 values. A small example would look like:
{8.206,8.206,8.201,8.196,8.193,8.192,8.189,8.174,8.171,8.171,8.166,8.163,8.157,8.154,8.153,8.14,8.131}

My lower value is: 8.16
My upper value is: 8.17

I need to get back: {8.171,8.171,8.166,8.163,8.157}

Comment: More information and sample data would be helpful. Do the *next* upper and lower values sequentially follow the upper and lower values? Are you providing those values for use during filtration, or should the code figure it out? Give us some sample data and show us what output is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
Dim myData As New List(Of someData) 
myData = sorceData.Where(Function(i) i.somevalue >= myLowervalue And i.somevalue <= myUpperValue).ToList 
myData = myData.Concat(sorceData.Where(Function(i) i.somevalue > myUpperValue).Take(1).ToList).ToList 
myData = myData.Concat(sorceData.Where(Function(i) i.somevalue < myLowervalue ).Take(1).ToList).ToList
```

It's not a single expression, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In C# but there is a similar VB equivalent. Something like this should work **(untested)**:

...

```
enum RangeRelation {Below, InRange, Above};
```

...

```
mySetOfNumbers    
.Select(number =>
  new {
    Number = number,
    RangeRelation = 
             number < lowerBound ? RangeRelation.Below : 
             number > upperBound ? RangeRelation.Above :
             RangeRelation.InRange
  })
  .GroupBy(x=>x.RangeRelation)
  .SelectMany(group =>
    group.Key == RangeRelation.Below ?  
       ( group.Any() ? new [] { group.OrderBy(x=>x).Last() } : new double[0] ) :
    group.Key == RangeRelation.Above ? 
       ( group.Any() ? new [] { group.OrderBy(x=>x).First() } : new double[0] ) :
    group
  );
```

It's ok if there is some question over whether the results will ever be fully enumerated since the delayed execution might work in your favor; however, if you are definitely using all of the resulting values I doubt that this will be compiled to something efficient.

That is to say, the `GroupBy()` has to traverse the set once, the new type needs to be created, and then the `OrderBy()` is going to be something like **O(n*log n)** time for both the Above and Below range values.  This is as opposed to something like this:

```
double? above = null;
double? below = null;
var selected = new List<double>();
foreach(var number in mySetOfNumbers)
  if(number < lowerBound && number > below??Double.MinValue)
   below = number;
  else if(number > upperBound && number < above??Double.MaxValue)
   above = number;
  else
   selected.Add(number);

if(above != null) selected.Add(above);
if(below != null) selected.Add(below);

return selected;
```

Which only requires a single enumeration.

That being said...for 150 values optimization doesn't matter at all.